# Extracting a Numbers from a String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, extract

I'd like to extract the numbers from the string. (E.g. I want the `24` and `380` from the string `24:380`) I'd like to assign it in respective variables. Is there any way I could do that?

I couldn't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: `"24:380".split(":").map(Number)`

Comment: Have you tried `split()`? also needs more details about your question

Comment: Oh I will try this one.

Comment: How do I assign it to the respective variables?

Comment: The general solution of _extracting_ (as opposed to splitting on a delimiter) would be `("24:380".match(/\d+/gu) ?? []).map(Number)`. You then get an array. How you assign this depends on context. `const [ first, last ] = ("24:380".match(/\d+/gu) ?? []).map(Number);` would be one approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [RegEx](https://%20%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```
const paragraph = 'The quick brown 45 jumps over the lazy 23:12. It barked.';
const regex = /(\d+)/g;
const found = paragraph.match(regex);

console.log(found);
// expected output: Array ["45", "23", "12"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use match or split with regex:

```js
const str = '24:380';


// This returns exactly and only 24 and 380.
const regex = /24|380/g
const resultArr = str.match(regex);
for (const output of resultArr) console.log(output);
// output:
// 24
// 380


// This returns any string seperated by ':'.
const regex2 = /:/g
const resultArr2 = str.split(regex2)
for (const output of resultArr2) console.log(output);
// output:
// 24
// 380


// This returns any numbers seperated by any string that is not number.
const regex3 = /[0-9]+/g
const resultArr3 = str.match(regex3)
for (const output of resultArr3) console.log(output);
// output:
// 24
// 380
```